# Как обращаться к FXML полям класса из другого класса?

Tags: java, javafx

Проблема вот в чём: я делаю чат, у меня есть два класса, Client(далее клиент)и View(далее представление),. Класс клиент отвечает за всю работу с сервером, и прослушку сообщений. Мне никак не удается передать это сообщение представлению, и проблема не так просто на первый взгляд. К классе представления есть такое поле:

```
@FXML
private TextArea messages;
```

Так как оно не статическое, то к нему нельзя обращаться из статических методов, следовательно, сделать в представлении статический метод, что просто будет добавлять новое сообщение не выйдет. Так же, нельзя создать экземпляр класса представления, так как оно является контроллером для FXML компонентов(не запутайтесь:-) ). Если попытаться создать, то программа упадет с кучей ошибок, предполагаю, что Java сама неявно создаёт один экземпляр с помощью рекурсии
. Пытался так же сделать представление синглтоном, но это не помогло.
Сделать поле статическим тоже не помогает, ничего не выйдет.
Так есть ли какой-то способ передать текст из нестатического метода клиент в нестатический метод представления?

Answer (score 0):

Класс клиент создается видимо где-то в классе Main/Application или чем-то подобном. Сделайте вместо этого там третий класс, который и будет синглтоном и будет хранить и инициировать в себе клиента. Как я понял вью - это и есть fx контроллер. После того как fx фреймворк создаст экземпляр вью он вызывает нестатичный метод @FXML initialize(), каких либо наследований от интерфейса не требуется (какой у него будет модификатор доступа рефлексии тоже без разницы), и там уже попросите новый синглтон выдать вам экземпляр клиента. И мы на коленке получили подобие dependency injection. Потом можно будет переделать покрасивее через DI библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

я конечно может что-то не допонял, но почему вы не можете воспользоваться геттером т.к.
`из нестатического метода клиент в нестатический метод представления`

не статический -> в нестатический

```java
@FXML
private TextArea messages;
... 
public String getMessage() { 
    if(messages != null) {
        return messageges.getText();
    }
    return "";
}

public void setMessage(String mess) { 
    if(messages != null) {
        messageges.setText(mess);
    }
}
```

да и, так конечно делать не стоит, но и

```java
@FXML
public TextArea messages;
```

обычно работал

Либо, если проблема в доступе, то ничего не мешает вам создать контроллер там где вы хотите.

Структура

[image: structure]

В данном случае фрагмент отвечает за всю логику, и отдаёт команды вью, он же контроллер, что делать. Фрагмент подписывается на события Клиента, и когда происходит событие отдаёт команду Контроллеру(он же вью).

BaseController

```java
package com.main.base;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public abstract class BaseController<E extends BaseFragment> implements Initializable {
    private final Scene scene;
    protected E fragment;

    public BaseController(E fragment ,String fxmlPath){
        this.fragment = fragment;
        scene = loadScene(fxmlPath);
    }

    private Scene loadScene(String fxmlPath) {
        if (!fxmlPath.equals("")){
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
                loader.setController(this);
                return new Scene(loader.load());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("FXML load error" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Scene getScene() {
        return scene;
    }
}
```

BaseFragment

```
package com.main.base;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

public abstract class BaseFragment<E extends BaseController> {
    protected E controller;

    protected abstract void onAttach();

    public Scene getScene() {
        if (controller != null) {
            return controller.getScene();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

EventListener

```java
package com.main.events;

public interface EventListeners {
}
```

OnNewMessageEvent

```java
package com.main.events;

public interface OnNewMessageEvent extends EventListeners {
    void onNewMessageEvent(String message);
}
```

MessageController

```java
package com.main.fragment;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.main.base.BaseController;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class MessageController extends BaseController<MessagesFragment> {

    @FXML
    private TextArea messages;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        messages.setText(message);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return messages.getText();
    }

    public MessageController(MessagesFragment fragment, String fxmlPath) {
        super(fragment, fxmlPath);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(messages, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(messages, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(messages, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(messages, 10.0);
        messages.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1");
    }
}
```

MessageFragment

```java
package com.main.fragment;

import com.main.base.BaseFragment;
import com.main.events.OnNewMessageEvent;
import javafx.application.Platform;

public class MessagesFragment extends BaseFragment<MessageController> implements OnNewMessageEvent {
    public MessagesFragment(){
        controller = new MessageController(this, "/fxml/test.fxml");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach() { }

    @Override
    public void onNewMessageEvent(String message) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            controller.setMessage(message);
        });
    }
}
```

Client

```java
package com.main;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.main.events.EventListeners;
import com.main.events.OnNewMessageEvent;

public class Client {
    private final Set<EventListeners> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    public void addListener(EventListeners audioListener) {
        listeners.add(audioListener);
    }

    public void removeListener(EventListeners audioListener) {
        listeners.remove(audioListener);
    }

    public void eventGeneratorMetod() {
        // тут что-то происходит, как-то определяем что пришло сообщение
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(//просто для генерации события
            () -> {
                while(true) {
                    fireEventNewMessage(randomString());// как-то так генерим событие
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        System.out.println("GO TO SLEEP");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private void fireEventNewMessage(String newMessage) {
        listeners.forEach(eventListeners -> {
            if (eventListeners instanceof OnNewMessageEvent){
                ((OnNewMessageEvent) eventListeners).onNewMessageEvent(newMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    private String randomString() {
        byte[] array = new byte[7];
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        return generatedString;
    }
}
```

Main

```java
package com.main;

import com.main.fragment.MessagesFragment;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Client connectionLogic = new Client();
        MessagesFragment messFragment = new MessagesFragment();
        connectionLogic.addListener(messFragment);
        primaryStage.setScene(messFragment.getScene());
        primaryStage.show();
        connectionLogic.eventGeneratorMetod();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Test.fxml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
<TextArea fx:id="messages" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">

</TextArea>
</AnchorPane>
```